# Talend: tMap not accepting lookup connection

Tags: mapping, talend

I have database queries which returns two sets of data from the same table. I need to map the results of those queries to each other based on the values they have in common. This is how far I got:

[image: Talend Screenshot]

My original idea was to use the output from tLogRow_2 as a lookup, but Talend won't let me do that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a closed loop in Talend. You need to remove the 2nd OnComponentOk link (to tMysqlInput_1) if you want to use that output as a lookup. You only need to hook the OnComponentOk trigger to the first component of your next subjob (a startable component).